# Dynamic SQL with Dynamic column names

Tags: sql, select, dynamic

I am trying to build a query that will return 13 columns that will display MTBF for a manufacturing facility. This is for a rolling calendar year by month. I have the formula working but, what I'm having trouble with is when I try to add more then one column and name that column with the 'as' function.

Any pointers are appreciated.

This is what the results should look like.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWQK1.jpg)

Here is what I have so far.

```
Declare @CurrentDate as DateTime

Declare @PreviousMonth as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth1 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd1 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString1 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd1 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName1 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth2 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd2 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString2 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd2 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName2 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth3 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd3 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString3 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd3 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName3 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth4 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd4 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString4 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd4 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName4 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth5 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd5 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString5 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd5 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName5 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth6 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd6 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString6 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd6 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName6 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth7 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd7 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString7 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd7 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName7 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth8 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd8 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString8 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd8 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName8 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth9 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd9 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString9 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd9 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName9 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth10 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd10 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString10 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd10 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName10 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth11 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd11 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString11 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd11 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName11 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth12 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd12 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString12 as VarChar(Max)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd12 as VarChar(Max)
Declare @PreviousMonthName12 as Varchar(Max)

Declare @SQLString as Varchar(Max)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 1)
        SET @PreviousMonth = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-1,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-1,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 2)
        SET @PreviousMonth1 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-2,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth1 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-2,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 3)
        SET @PreviousMonth2 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-3,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth2 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-3,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 4)
        SET @PreviousMonth3 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-4,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth3 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-4,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 5)
        SET @PreviousMonth4 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-5,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth4 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-5,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 6)
        SET @PreviousMonth5 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-6,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth5 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-6,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 7)
        SET @PreviousMonth6 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-7,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth6 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-7,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 8)
        SET @PreviousMonth7 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-8,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth7 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-8,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 9)
        SET @PreviousMonth8 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-9,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth8 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-9,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 10)
        SET @PreviousMonth9 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-10,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth10 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-10,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 11)
        SET @PreviousMonth11 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-11,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth11 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-11,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 12)
        SET @PreviousMonth12 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-12,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth12 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-12,getdate())),01)

SET @PreviousMonthName = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth)
SET @PreviousMonthName1 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth1)
SET @PreviousMonthName2 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth2)
SET @PreviousMonthName3 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth3)
SET @PreviousMonthName4 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth4)
SET @PreviousMonthName5 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth5)
SET @PreviousMonthName6 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth6)
SET @PreviousMonthName7 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth7)
SET @PreviousMonthName8 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth8)
SET @PreviousMonthName9 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth9)
SET @PreviousMonthName10 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth10)
SET @PreviousMonthName11 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth11)
SET @PreviousMonthName12 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth12)

SET @PreviousMonthString = Cast(@PreviousMonth as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString1 = Cast(@PreviousMonth1 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString2 = Cast(@PreviousMonth2 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString3 = Cast(@PreviousMonth3 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString4 = Cast(@PreviousMonth4 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString5 = Cast(@PreviousMonth5 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString6 = Cast(@PreviousMonth6 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString7 = Cast(@PreviousMonth7 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString8 = Cast(@PreviousMonth8 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString9 = Cast(@PreviousMonth9 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString10 = Cast(@PreviousMonth10 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString11 = Cast(@PreviousMonth11 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString12 =  Cast(@PreviousMonth12 as VarChar(20))

Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd1 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth1) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd2 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth2) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd3 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth3) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd4 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth4) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd5 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth5) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd6 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth6) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd7 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth7) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd8 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth8) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd9 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth9) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd10 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth10) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd11 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth11) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd12 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth12) as VarChar(Max))

Declare @Formula as VarChar(Max)
Declare @From as Varchar(Max)
Declare @Where as Varchar(Max)

Set @Formula = 'Cast(Round((COUNT (Distinct wojob.AssetID) *365.0)/(COUNT(*)),2) as Numeric(36,2))'
Set @From = 'FROM [Maint5k].[dbo].[woJob] INNER JOIN Maint5k.dbo.syJobType ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID INNER JOIN Maint5k.dbo.pmAsset ON woJob.AssetID = pmAsset.AssetID'
Set @Where = ' and (pmAsset.Usertext2 = ''Critical'' or pmAsset.Usertext2 = ''Constraint'')) '

Set @SQLString = 'Select (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString12 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd12 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName12 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString11 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd11 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName11 + '''),''    
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString10 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd10 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName10 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString9 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd9 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName9 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString8 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd8 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName8 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString7 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd7 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName7 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString6 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd6 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName6 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString5 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd5 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName5 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString4 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd4 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName4 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString3 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd3 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName3 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString2 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd2 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName2 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString1 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd1 + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName1 + '''),''
                         (Select ' + @Formula + ' ' + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd + ''' as ''' + @PreviousMonthName + ''')'



    --print(@SQLString)
    Execute(@SQLString)
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Wanted to update the post in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

```
Declare @CurrentDate as DateTime

Declare @CurrentMonth as DateTime
Declare @CurrentMonthEnd as DateTime
Declare @CurrentMonthString as VarChar(20)
Declare @CurrentMonthStringEnd as VarChar(20)
Declare @CurrentMonthName as Varchar(20)


Declare @PreviousMonth as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth1 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd1 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString1 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd1 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName1 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth2 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd2 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString2 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd2 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName2 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth3 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd3 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString3 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd3 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName3 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth4 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd4 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString4 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd4 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName4 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth5 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd5 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString5 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd5 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName5 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth6 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd6 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString6 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd6 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName6 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth7 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd7 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString7 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd7 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName7 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth8 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd8 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString8 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd8 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName8 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth9 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd9 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString9 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd9 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName9 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth10 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd10 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString10 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd10 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName10 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth11 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd11 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString11 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd11 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName11 as Varchar(20)

Declare @PreviousMonth12 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthEnd12 as DateTime
Declare @PreviousMonthString12 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthStringEnd12 as VarChar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonthName12 as Varchar(20)

Declare @SQLString as Varchar(Max)
Declare @SQLString1 as Varchar(Max)
Declare @SQLString2 as Varchar(Max)
Declare @SQLString3 as Varchar(Max)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 1)
        SET @PreviousMonth = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-1,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-1,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 2)
        SET @PreviousMonth1 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-2,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth1 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-2,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 3)
        SET @PreviousMonth2 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-3,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth2 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-3,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 4)
        SET @PreviousMonth3 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-4,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth3 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-4,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 5)
        SET @PreviousMonth4 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-5,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth4 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-5,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 6)
        SET @PreviousMonth5 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-6,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth5 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-6,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 7)
        SET @PreviousMonth6 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-7,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth6 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-7,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 8)
        SET @PreviousMonth7 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-8,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth7 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-8,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 9)
        SET @PreviousMonth8 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-9,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth8 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-9,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 10)
        SET @PreviousMonth9 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-10,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth9 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-10,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 11)
        SET @PreviousMonth10 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-11,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth10 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-11,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 12)
        SET @PreviousMonth11 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-12,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth11 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-12,getdate())),01)

IF (DatePart(mm,getdate()) > 13)
        SET @PreviousMonth12 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate()),month(dateadd(Month,-13,getdate())),01)
    Else
        SET @PreviousMonth12 = DateFromParts(datepart(yyyy,getdate())-1,month(dateadd(Month,-13,getdate())),01)


SET @CurrentMonthName = DateName(Month,getdate())
SET @PreviousMonthName = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth)
SET @PreviousMonthName1 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth1)
SET @PreviousMonthName2 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth2)
SET @PreviousMonthName3 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth3)
SET @PreviousMonthName4 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth4)
SET @PreviousMonthName5 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth5)
SET @PreviousMonthName6 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth6)
SET @PreviousMonthName7 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth7)
SET @PreviousMonthName8 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth8)
SET @PreviousMonthName9 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth9)
SET @PreviousMonthName10 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth10)
SET @PreviousMonthName11 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth11)
SET @PreviousMonthName12 = DateName(Month,@PreviousMonth12)

SET @CurrentMonthString = Cast(@CurrentMonth as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString = Cast(@PreviousMonth as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString1 = Cast(@PreviousMonth1 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString2 = Cast(@PreviousMonth2 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString3 = Cast(@PreviousMonth3 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString4 = Cast(@PreviousMonth4 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString5 = Cast(@PreviousMonth5 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString6 = Cast(@PreviousMonth6 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString7 = Cast(@PreviousMonth7 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString8 = Cast(@PreviousMonth8 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString9 = Cast(@PreviousMonth9 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString10 = Cast(@PreviousMonth10 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString11 = Cast(@PreviousMonth11 as VarChar(20))
SET @PreviousMonthString12 =  Cast(@PreviousMonth12 as VarChar(20))

Set @CurrentMonthStringEnd = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,getDate()) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd1 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth1) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd2 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth2) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd3 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth3) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd4 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth4) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd5 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth5) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd6 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth6) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd7 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth7) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd8 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth8) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd9 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth9) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd10 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth10) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd11 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth11) as VarChar(20))
Set @PreviousMonthStringEnd12 = Cast(Dateadd(Day,-365,@previousMonth12) as VarChar(20))

Declare @Formula as VarChar(100)
Declare @From as Varchar(200)
Declare @Where as Varchar(100)

Set @Formula = 'Cast(Round((COUNT (Distinct wojob.AssetID) *365.0)/(COUNT(*)),2) as Numeric(36,2))'
Set @From = ' FROM [Maint5k].[dbo].[woJob] INNER JOIN Maint5k.dbo.syJobType ON woJob.JobTypeID = syJobType.JobTypeID INNER JOIN Maint5k.dbo.pmAsset ON woJob.AssetID = pmAsset.AssetID'
Set @Where = ' and (pmAsset.Usertext2 = ''Critical'' or pmAsset.Usertext2 = ''Constraint'')'

Declare @Select12 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select11 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select10 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select9 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select8 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select7 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select6 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select5 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select4 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select3 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select2 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select1 as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @Select as VarChar(MAX)
Declare @SelectCurrent as VarChar(MAX)


SET @Select12 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString12 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd12 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName12
SET @Select11 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString11 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd11 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName11
SET @Select10 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString10 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd10 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName10
SET @Select9 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString9 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd9 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName9
SET @Select8 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString8 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd8 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName8
SET @Select7 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString7 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd7 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName7
SET @Select6 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString6 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd6 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName6
SET @Select5 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString5 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd5 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName5
SET @Select4 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString4 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd4 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName4
SET @Select3 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString3 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd3 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName3
SET @Select2 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString2 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd2 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName2
SET @Select1 = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString1 + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd1 + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName1
SET @Select = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @PreviousMonthString + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @PreviousMonthStringEnd + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @PreviousMonthName
SET @SelectCurrent = ' (Select ' + @Formula + @From + ' Where syJobType.IsBreakDown = ''1'' and woJob.StartDate < ''' + @CurrentMonthString + ''' and woJob.StartDate > ''' + @CurrentMonthStringEnd + '''' + @Where + ')' + ' as ' + @CurrentMonthName

Print @SelectCurrent

Declare @Set1 as VarChar(Max)
Declare @Set2 as VarChar(Max)
Declare @Set3 as VarChar(Max)
Declare @Set4 as VarChar(Max)
Declare @Set5 as VarChar(Max)

Set @Set1 = @Select12 + ',' + @Select11 + ',' + @Select10 + ','
Set @Set2 = @Select9 + ',' + @Select8 + ',' + @Select7 + ','
Set @Set3 = @Select6 + ',' + @Select5 + ',' + @Select4 + ','
Set @Set4 = @Select3 + ',' + @Select2 + ',' + @Select1 + ',' + @Select --+ ','
Set @Set5 = @SelectCurrent



Print @SelectCurrent


Set @SQLString = 'Select ' + @Set1 + @Set2 + @Set3 + @Set4 --+ @Set5

Execute(@SQLString)
```